# Railsで localhost:3000/home/topに接続できません。

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Railsのサーバーについて質問です。

windows10で環境構築をして、`rails s` でサーバーを立ち上げた後、 localhost:3000 に接続はできました。
しかし、`rails g controller home top` コマンドを実行後、 localhost:3000/home/top とURLを入力しても、ビューページに接続できないので、解決方法を教えていただきたいです。

エラーが出るというわけではなく、どれだけ待ってもページが表示されない感じです。
ルーティングに設定してないURLを入力すると、ちゃんとエラーがでます。

＊試したこと

- `rails new` でアプリをもう一度作り直す
- ウイルス対策ソフトを停止
- ルーテイング、アクション、ビューの見直し
- scaffold でもやってみました

＊コマンドプロンプト上の表示内容

- localhost:3000/home/top にアクセスした時

  ```
  Started GET "/home/top" for ::1 at 2019-06-09 17:20:28 +0900
  Processing by HomeController#top as HTML
  Rendering home/top.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered home/top.html.erb within layouts/application (0.3ms)
  ```
- localhost:3000 にアクセスした時

  ```
  Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2019-06-09 17:26:58 +0900
  Processing by Rails::WelcomeController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"internal"=>true}
  Rendering C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/templates/rails/welcome/index.html.erb
  Rendered C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/templates/rails/welcome/index.html.erb (1.4ms)
  Completed 200 OK in 15ms (Views: 9.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
  ```

＊ルーティング　（下記の２種で試しました）

```rb
　get 'home/top' => 'home#top'
```

```rb
　get 'home/top'
```

＊アクション

```rb
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def top
  end
end
```

＊ビュー

```html
<h1>Home#top</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/home/top.html.erb</p>
```

ググっても同じようなエラーの解決について見つからないので、途方に暮れています......
お手数ですが、回答いただきたいです。
よろしくお願いします。

追記:下記がコマンドプロンプトで"rake routes"を実行後の結果です。

```
  Prefix Verb URI Pattern         Controller#Action
home_top GET  /home/top(.:format) home#top
```

Comment: 不思議ですね。コマンドラインで`rake routes`するとルーティング一覧が表示されますので、その結果を追記してもらっていいですか？

Comment: 返答ありがとうございます。
質問文の一番下に"rake routes" を実行後の結果を追記しましたので、確認していただきたいです。

Answer (score 0):

rubyを再インストールし直したら、解決しました。
原因はわかりません。